# How to convert factor format to numeric format in R without changing the values?

Tags: r, numeric, r-factor

Below is dataframe df1 of which I want to convert column "V2" from factor format to numeric without changing the current values (0 ; 0 ; 8,5 ; 3).

df1=

```
             V1  V2 V3       X2 X3
4470 2010-03-28   0  A 21.53675  0
4471 2010-03-29   0  A 19.21611  0
4472 2010-03-30 8,5  A 21.54541  0
4473 2010-03-31   3  A       NA NA
```

Since column "V2" is in factor format I first convert it to character format:
`df1[,2]=as.character(df1[,2])`

Then I try to convert "V2" to numeric format:

`df1[,2]=as.numeric(df1[,2])`

Leading to this R message:

`Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion`

And the dataframe below where `df[3,2]` has changed into "NA" instead of remaining "8,5"..

```
             V1 V2 V3       X2 X3
4470 2010-03-28  0  A 21.53675  0
4471 2010-03-29  0  A 19.21611  0
4472 2010-03-30 NA  A 21.54541  0
4473 2010-03-31  3  A       NA NA
```

It might have to do with the fact that 8,5 is not a whole number. Still I do not know how to solve this problem. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem here is that your decimal separation is with a comma instead of a point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace comma's with dots, which represent decimals in R. Otherwise R thinks it is a character and coerces the value to NA.

Then, to extract values:

```
as.numeric(levels(df1[,2])[df[,2]])
```

(thanks @SimonO101 for the correction)

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks, I tested it on your `fac` vector initially and therefore missed it.

Comment: Thx for you respons. How do I change comma's to dots in R? This dataframe is actually part of a much larger one. Cannot do it by hand.

Comment: MB123: @SimonO101 already posted it.

Answer (score 12):

Try this to replace the comma in your data:

```
fac<- c( "0" , "0" , "1,5" , "0" , "0" , "8" )
#[1] "0"   "0"   "1,5" "0"   "0"   "8" 
fac <- as.numeric( sub(",", ".", fac) )
#[1] 0.0 0.0 1.5 0.0 0.0 8.0
```

More generally converting factors to their underlying values rather than the factor representation:

```
fac <- as.factor( fac )
as.numeric(fac)
#[1] 1 1 2 1 1 3
as.numeric(as.character(fac))
#[1] 0.0 0.0 1.5 0.0 0.0 8.0
```

However, this is the canonical way of transforming to original values

```
 as.numeric(levels(fac))[fac]
```

From the help page `?as.factor`

> In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Comment: Hi @SimonO101 would `gsub` be an alternative formulation in case the OP had more than one data point with commas in their data frame?

Comment: @TahnoonPasha try it on `fac<- c( "0" , "0" , "1,5" , "0,6" , "0" , "8" )`. Here `sub` works on each element of the vector, so s long as each number has only one comma then it's ok. I am assuming that they only have one comma in each number of their data.frame because if they have more than one then using `gsub` probably won't help because you end up with a number with two decimal points in it!!! So it get's converted to NA anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code after you converted to character:

```
df[3,2] <- 8.5
```

You should then be able to convert characters to numerics. Since R's default decimal separator is `.` and not `,`, your value is replaced by NA without that step.