# Convert character to number without the loss of decimal in R

Tags: r

We have seen many questions regarding **How to save the decimal places while converting factors to numbers** such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/1247080) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16335516/1247080). But I did not see anything that do the same with character data instead of factor data. Below is what I tried without success:

```
f1 <- c("402313.01399128098", "402896.30908451998", "403165.63827027398", "403169.06116369402", "402891.96329268801", "402239.74412469601", 
        "402271.54950727499", "402313.01399128098")
as.numeric(as.character(f1)) # does not work

f2 <- as.factor(f1) 
as.numeric(as.character(f2)) # my decimals are GONE

f3 <- levels(f2) 
as.numeric(f3) # my decimals are gone again
```

I get this

```
[1] 402239.7 402271.5 402313.0 402892.0 402896.3 403165.6 403169.1
```

#### Update after the answer/comments:

There was no loss of decimal places. But I do not know why it was not showing.  With `options(digits = 15)` I could see all the decimals.

**Lesson**: You may run `options()` before you decide to ask such questions.

Comment: I don't think you're losing anything.  You're only seeing the values represented with a different number of decimal places.

Comment: @Minnow, the R inferno (which I love) talks about finite-precision representation of numbers, but it doesn't talk (as much) about the difference between internal structure and external representation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the digits are still there. That is just the default printing method.

```
new.vec <- as.numeric(f1)
print(new.vec, digits=20)
#[1] 402313.01399128098 402896.30908451998 403165.63827027398
#[4] 403169.06116369402 402891.96329268801 402239.74412469601
#[7] 402271.54950727499 402313.01399128098
```

You can also change the default with `options(digits = n)`.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r).

Comment: How would you store these values?

Comment: you could also compare with `as.character(as.numeric(f1))`